# problam java jsf selectonemenu

Tags: jsf

I have three parameters
country selectonemenu
city selectonemenu
inputtext city code

When I choose the country, will the city and the city code be shown to me in jsf?
I am using jdbc
also
im uset intellj ide

java jsf selectonemenu form